# groupby rows from several columns in list in python pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have Pandas DataFrame that looks like:

```
    id     a    b    c       col
1   a      1    2    Null    'aa'
2   a      2    2    3       'aa'
3   b      4    3    1       'bb'
4   c      1    Null 3       'gg'
5   c      Null 2    Null    'gg'
```

I want to groupby the columns to get the following:

```
    id     new_col           col
1   a      [1, 2, 2, 2, 3]   'aa'
2   b      [4, 3, 1]         'bb'
3   c      [1, 3, 2]         'gg'
```

Is it possible to do it using pd.groupby?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) by all columns without specified in list by [`Index.difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html):

```
df = df.replace('Null', np.nan)

c = df.columns.difference(['id','col'])
f = lambda x: x.stack().tolist()
df = df.groupby(['id','col'])[c].apply(f).reset_index(name='new_col')[['id','new_col','col']]
print (df)
  id          new_col   col
0  a  [1, 2, 2, 2, 3]  'aa'
1  b        [4, 3, 1]  'bb'
2  c        [1, 3, 2]  'gg'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`df.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) with [`groupby+agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22.0/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html):

```
final = (df.replace('Null',np.nan).melt(['id','col'],value_name='new_col').groupby('id'
         ,as_index=False).agg({'new_col':lambda x: x.dropna().tolist(),'col':'first'}))
```

Or [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) first with `set_index` then `groupby+agg`

```
final1 = (df.replace('Null',np.nan).set_index(['id','col']).stack().rename('new_col')
       .reset_index('col').groupby(level=0).agg({'new_col':list,'col':'first'}))
```

---

```
  id          new_col   col
0  a  [1, 2, 2, 2, 3]  'aa'
1  b        [4, 3, 1]  'bb'
2  c        [1, 2, 3]  'gg'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df["d"] = df[['a', 'b', 'c']].values.tolist()
dup = df.groupby(['id','col'])['d'].sum().reset_index(name='new_col')
```